# how to use ajax panel extender's click event to call a method in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to use `ajax` panel extender such that on click of `ExpandControlID` or `CollapseControlID` should call a method.

Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add New Panel :

```
       <asp:Panel ID="pnlClick" runat="server" CssClass="pnlCSS">
        <div style="background-image:url('green_bg.gif'); height:30px; vertical-align:middle">
         <div style="float:left; color:White;padding:5px 5px 0 0">
     Alert Panel
      </div>
         <div style="float:left; color:White; padding:5px 5px 0 0">
       <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Label"/>
      <asp:Image ID="imgArrows" runat="server" />
       </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      </div>
       </asp:Panel>
```

Step2 :

Add Your Panel Which is to be Hide and Show on Click

```
        <asp:Panel ID="panel 5" runat="server" >

       </asp:Panel>
```

Step 3 :

Below your panel , Add CollapsiblePanelExtender

```
  <cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" runat="server"
   CollapseControlID="pnlClick" Collapsed="true" ExpandControlID="pnlClick" TextLabelID="lblMessage"
    CollapsedText="Show" ExpandedText="Hide" ImageControlID="imgArrows"
   CollapsedImage="~/Client/Images/CollapseExpand/downarrow.jpg" ExpandedImage="~/Client/Images/CollapseExpand/uparrow.jpg" ExpandDirection="Vertical"   TargetControlID="Panel5" ScrollContents="false">
  </cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Step : 4

Add your CSS

Eg:

```
     <style type="text/css">
     .pnlCSS{
     font-weight: bold;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
     width:10%;
     }
     </style>
```